# Dynamically Identify entity class and JPA Interface

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have a requirement that based on profile I need to inject 2 different classes into DAO layer to perform CRUD operation. Let's say we have class A and Class B for profiles a and b respectively. Now in the DAO layer without using if else condition (As I am using that currently based on the profile, I am using service layer to call 2 different methods 1.saveA(), 2.saveB().) But is there any way to make it more generic and based on profile or either by the class reference I can instantiate different entity as well as JPA Classes? I tried to use

```
<T extends Parent> T factoryMethod(Class<T> clazz) throws Exception {
        return (T) clazz.newInstance();
    }
```

but this also will force me to cast the returned object to a class. I tried creating a parent P for both class A and B. and used them instead but got confused when injecting the entity types to JPARepository.
I tried creating a SimpleJPARepository but didnt worked as there are overridden methods in ARepository and BRepository.
Or, 
is there a way I can use the same entity class for 2 different tables? that way it can be solved. for 1 profile I have different sets of columns whereas for 2nd profile I have different columns.

this is how I am expecting: Would it be possible? or, how I am doing now is correct?

```
public void doStuff(Class<T> class){
   GenericRepository repo;
   if(class instanceof A){
     //use ARepository;
     repo = applicationContext.getBean(ARepository);
   }else{
      //use BRepository;
     repo = applicationContext.getBean(BRepository);
   }
   repo.save(class);
   repo.flush();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method utility like following: The `key` is the class type of the entity and the `value` is the repository.

```
  Map<Class<? extends Parent>, JpaRepository> repoMapping = new HashMap<>();

  @PostConstruct
  public void init(){
    repoMapping.put(A.class, applicationContext.getBean(ARepository));
    repoMapping.put(B.class, applicationContext.getBean(BRepository));
  }
  public JpaRepository getRepo(Class<? extends Parent> classs){
     return repoMapping.get(classs);
  }
```

Comment: Adria if I autowire ARepository and BRespository and pass to the Map. I am getting the below Compiler error:```The method put(Class<? extends Parent>, capture#1-of ? extends JpaRepository) in the type Map<Class<? extends Parent>,capture#1-of ? extends JpaRepository> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<A>, ARepository)```

Comment: remove the part `? extends` and try with ` Map<Class<? extends Parent>, JpaRepository`. I updated the answer.